# Create a dynamic playlist HTML5 audio player

Tags: html, dynamic, playlist

I need to create a player like the one found on http://www.beatport.com

It's HTML5 based and songs are added dynamically via playlist links located on the site. 
I know it is a two part work but the player & playlist management is the key.

Answer (score 2):

visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333670/Audio-Gallery-Suite-A-complete-audio-gallery-solut

It is an open source perfect for creating dynamic html5 audio player. You are going to love it.

Comment: Thanks! http://www.wemakedancemusic.com is the project we are working on!